# CPU frequency limit to 2000 on battery

Tags: power-management, battery, cpu, cpufreq, frequency

I want set frequency to 2100 in battery mode but it have limit to 2000. I ran `tlp ac` and change CPU frequency with `indicator-cpufreq` to 2100 (and also check Performance) then check frequency with `lscpu` but maximum cpu frequency is 2000.

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq
acpi-cpufreq

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
userspace
```

Also I disable pstate wtih `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable resume=/dev/sda3"`

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
```

And

```
$ sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
2100000 2000000 1900000 1800000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1200000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000
```

Comment: And the question is...?  I see nothing but facts.

Comment: As Rinz says, what is the question?

Comment: @Rinzwind I want set frequency to 2100 in battery mode. Thanks...

Comment: @Tim I update the question, Could you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1):

Not all pstates are available when using acpi-cpufreq. You can check the available frequencies (pstates) via:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

Is 2100 listed?
If it is listed, what do you get for:

```
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo
```

and

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
```

Based on your comments, it appears to be set for 2000 Max, regardless of what some tool says. I don't use such tools, I would do this:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "userspace" > $file; done
for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed; do echo "2100000" > $file; done

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: Yes, 2100000 is available in battery mode. Thanks for your attention

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable  resume=/dev/sda3"`

Comment: I get `cpu MHz  : 2000.000`

Comment: Got `1200000
2000000
2000000
2000000`

Comment: Nothing happened, `userspace
userspace
userspace
userspace
userspace
userspace
userspace
userspace
cpu MHz  : 2000.000
cpu MHz  : 2000.000
cpu MHz  : 2000.000
cpu MHz  : 2000.000` Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you run it as sudo? And perhaps post the available frequencies list into your question.

Comment: I wonder if some daemon related to the other stuff is still running, clobbering what we are trying to do manually. This stuff works on my computer, and if I ask for a frequency (pstate) that is not available, it seems to select the next one higher, not lower.

Comment: Do you have any idea to check if some daemon do that?

Comment: Well yes, cpufreqd

Comment: Could you please add the list of available frequencies to your question. Could you also add your processor details. `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"`